# Adding arrays of L1 cache size. Large arrays are absolute faster than short arrays

Tags: c++, performance, caching

Good morning,

I wrote the following program to add two arrays:

```
#include<iostream>

#define line 32
inline void add(float a[], float b[]){
  for (int i=0; i<line; i++){a[i]+=b[i];}
}

int main(){
float a[line]; for (int i=0; i<line; i++){a[i]=0.;}
float b[line]; for (int i=0; i<line; i++){b[i]=0.;}

for (int i=0; i<1024*1024*512; i++){add(a,b);} //Add arrays several times
for (int i=0; i<line; i++){std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;} //Print arrays, else -05 optimize it away.
}
```

I compiled it with (g++ version 4.8.4 / my hardware is older)

```
 g++ add.c++ -O5 -o Test
```

and run it with

```
time ./Test
```

if line=32 then it needs 1.3 seconds

if line=16 then it needs 2.3 seconds

I tried it several times and the run-time is always the same (so it's stable.)
I understand, that a large array can be relatively faster (vector processors etc.), but I don't understand, why it is absolute faster. I wrote this program to figure out how to achieve Peak-Performance. My question: What is going on there in the CPU and how can I improve it?

Comment: That's an array. C++ vectors' type is `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler will be able to unroll loops with hard coded limits like 16/32/64 very easily. It's likely that unrolling your "32 times" loop and using AVX results in exactly 4 AVX additions. This is going to be faster than a "16 times" loop which results in 2 AVX additions as there will likely be a pipeline stall when the branch happens to operate on each of your "lines" (unless you are running on something like a xeon which can speculatively execute several paths).

Microbenchmarks can be misleading unless done carefully so you should always look at the generated assembly. As your benchmark is just hitting the same memory over and over you should think about whether this is actually representative of what will happen in production.

Answer (score 1):

From your compile statement it's clear that, you are using `O5 optimization` to compile the code.

It is known that except that `O2 optimization` all others variant is not stable. I would suggest you not to use them for testing purpose and most importantly it's not well defined.

And also there could be many conditions here. Like `O5 optimization` may not actually work until your program consumes a large amount of memory or it's internal optimization algorithm detects heavy pressure on computation. Like I say `O5 optimization` is not well defined and stable. 
While I was coding I faces this type of problem and stop doing any `O.x optimization`.

I wish this helps.

Comment: You are right, the strange behavior occurs, if I go from -O2 to -O3. The line=32 suddenly becomes 7 times-faster while line=16 just improves by a factor 1.4.